# Error loading shared library test/libaegean.dll: No such file or directory

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

I am building an image from a dockerfile for a spring boot sample app, using the COPY command to copy a local file (which i need to pass as a vm argument) from host into my container.
The docker is running on windows 10 and with linux container.
When I try to run the image it shows error same as

```
Could not find agent library test/libaegean.dll in absolute path, with error: Error loading shared library test/libaegean.dll: No such file or directory.
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN mkdir test
RUN chmod +x test
COPY libaegean.dll test
COPY dellicence.lic test
COPY application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar test
WORKDIR test
EXPOSE 6070
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-agentpath:test/libaegean.dll","-jar","application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

This is how I am building the image

```
docker image build --file=Dockerfile --tag=sample .
```

This is how I am running the container

```
docker container run --name=sample sample
```

please look at the picture to have a clear idea.
Thank you for the help in advance.

[docker build image success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99EmN.png)

[docker run failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHpWi.png)

Comment: `test/libaegean.dll` is a relative folder, but when you copy your DLL, you copy it to test, which is your workdir. You don't need to add test in your `agentpath` parameter.

Comment: i tried with `-agentpath:libaegean.dll` and `-agentpath:/libaegean.dll` . still the issue persists.

Comment: `FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/libaegean.dll /app/lib
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/zkbiosecurityDev.lic /app/lib
COPY application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /
WORKDIR /
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","-agentpath:app/lib/libaegean.dll","-jar","/application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"] ` tried to do this . it seems to be starting but its not loading the libgen.dll file only . I am not sure what this "-cp" does. just googled and tried. Still not working.